# Finding equation of tangent plane to the surface $z = f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am given $f(x,y) = xe^y, P = (1,0,1)$. My first step is to take partial derivative, so $∂/∂x$ = $e^y$ and $∂/∂y$ = $xe^y$ so would my work simply be $e^y \times xe^y - z=0 => $ $e^1 \times 1e^0 - z + 1=0$ which would then equal (without calculator) $$e^1 \times 1 - z + 1 = 0$$ Any help is greatly appreciated, I understand what to do when you have an easier example (like $z = x^2 + y^2$) but I am having a little trouble with the more difficult syntax.

Comment: The surface is $\psi (x, y ,z) = 0$ and you need to calculate $grad(\psi)$ at P to get a normal vector to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of tangent plane at $P=(1,0,1)$ is $$z=1+a(x-1)+b(y-0)$$

where $a = \frac {\partial {f}}{\partial {x}}(1,0)$ and $b= \frac {\partial {f}}{\partial {y}}(1,0)$

Thus the equation of the tangent plane is simply  $$ z=1+(x-1)+(y-0)= x+y $$

Comment: so if the equation was $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ how would it differ? I am a little confused how you got that equation?

Comment: When the function changes, partial derivatives change, so does the equation of the tangent line. For #f(x,y)=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ the partials are $a = \frac {\partial {f}}{\partial {x}}(1,0)=1$ and b = \frac {\partial {f}}{\partial {y}}(1,0)=0$ thus the equation of tangent line at $(1,0,1)$ is $z=1+1(x-1)+0(y-0)= x$